# Angular project layout for front and admin area?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, javascript-framework

I'm new to Angular and am currently building a javascript heavy page that will have a frontend that is available to guests, and a user or admin area that is available to logged in users.

I also have a backend application written in PHP that provides me a RESTful API.

Now, I don't actually know how to structure my Angular app in order to avoid loading scripts in the admin area that are used only on the guest area and vice versa. My current project structure is the following:

```
web_root/
--app/
----css/
----img/
----js/
------controllers/
------services/
------app.js
------directives.js
------filters.js
----templates/
--index.html
```

In my index.html I load every javascript file separately. I don't know how to continue and build the admin area. Should I use another HTML file to load the relevant javascript files and another module?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just making a guess here but I'm going to say I think this probably depends on how much the code will be shared and how access will be restricted.  I have to do something similar my plan was basically to restrict everything using SESSIONS on the data side of things and just be sure not to build anything private into the admin interface itself so as to not have to worry about "protecting" it.  Client side I'll make a separate admin folder, but probably within the app folder so I can pretty easily reference things without copying.

Comment: I'm not planning on sharing much between the two sides, perhaps some layout, css and images. Should I just make two separate Angular apps then?

Comment: I think so, I mean the less sharing you'll be doing the more shoe-horning (trying to make it fit) you'll have to do, might as well have "the right sized shoe."  Unless sharing code saves you time I don't see any reason not to have a separate app.

Comment: Okay, and should I then create another folder and reference that if I want to access the user area? Ie. `www.example.com` is the guest area and `www.example.com/admin/` is the admin one? And each would have an `index.html` that loads the scripts and everything else I need.

Comment: Yup this is how I've handled it thus far and haven't run into any issues that I'm aware of yet.  I made a "seed" project for myself that is a stripped down angular project, then have another one with a bunch of components in it.  So I start with the seed, and pull stuff from the one that's loaded with components.  So far this is working out pretty well.

Comment: Thanks a lot, would you mind putting this in an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Örs I'll post as an answer once I have a bit of time to write it up properly, maybe someone else will chime in here with other opinions/reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have separate controllers for guess and admin related sections? Then tie those up to different partials based on the routes defined in routerProvider? That way you can use the single app, consolidate reusable code into filters/services/directives but only load data for the requested view.

Comment: Hi David, I tried this approach however I still download too many stuff that I have no need for on each side. I actually went with two different applications, while storing the user's session on the server.